# Database or no database?

Tags: php, database, pagination

```
<?php
$image_url = 'images/';

//User defined variables for page settings
$rows_per_page = 2;
$cols_per_page = 4;

//Master array of ALL the images in the order to be displayed
$images = array(
'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg',
'image5.jpg', 'image6.jpg', 'image7.jpg', 'image8.jpg',
'image9.jpg', 'image10.jpg', 'image11.jpg', 'image12.jpg',
'image13.jpg', 'image14.jpg', 'image15.jpg', 'image16.jpg',
'image17.jpg', 'image18.jpg', 'image19.jpg'
);

//END USER DEFINED VARIABLES

//System defined variable
$records_per_page = $rows_per_page * $cols_per_page;
$total_records = count($images);
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $records_per_page);

//Get/define current page
$current_page = (int) $_GET['page'];
if($current_page<1 || $current_page>$total_pages)
{
$current_page = 1;
}

//Get records for the current page
$page_images = array_splice($images, ($current_page-1)*$records_per_page, $records_per_page);

//Create ouput for the records of the current page
$ouput = "<table border=\"1\">\n";
for($row=0; $row<$rows_per_page; $row++)
{
$ouput .= "<tr>\n";
for($col=0; $col<$cols_per_page; $col++)
{
$imgIdx = ($row * $rows_per_page) + $col;
$img = (isset($page_images[$imgIdx])) ? "<img src=\"{$image_url}{$page_images[$imgIdx]}\" />" : '&nbsp;';
$ouput .= "<td>$img</td>\n";
}
$ouput .= "</tr>\n";
}
$ouput .= "</table>";

//Create pagination links
$first = "First";
$prev = "Prev";
$next = "Next";
$last = "Last";
if($current_page>1)
{
$prevPage = $current_page - 1;
$first = "<a href=\"test.php?page=1\">First</a>";
$prev = "<a href=\"test.php?page={$prevPage}\">Prev</a>";
}
if($current_page<$total_pages)
{
$nextPage = $current_page + 1;
$next = "<a href=\"test.php?page={$nextPage}\">Next</a>";
$last = "<a href=\"test.php?page={$total_pages}\">Last</a>";
}

?>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Here are the records for page <?php echo $current_page; ?></h2>
<ul>
<?php echo $ouput; ?>
</ul>
Page <?php echo $current_page; ?> of <?php echo $total_pages; ?>


<?php echo "{$first} | {$prev} | {$next} | {$last}"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This code above provides an easy way of putting up pictures to my site, whilst having the other pictures move automatically without the need of a database. But I must wonder: Would it make the page load faster if I moved my pictures to a database rather than what I'm doing right now? I mean the example above shows I'm only using 19 pictures, but if I ever reach say 1000 pictures, would the php file be too big? Should I just make a database now or it doesn't matter?

Also, for some reason, pagination is not working. Anyone care to do a diagnosis?

Thanks!

Comment: I've quickly tested your script, pagination seems to work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, if you ever have 1000 pictures the PHP file would be particularly large.  While this may well cause the load time to be slightly slower, arrays with 1000 elements are certainly not beyond the ability of PHP to handle efficiently.

Part (in fact, much) of the reason for using a database is that it is easier to manage large datasets.  With your current setup, what happens when you want to add pictures somewhere other than at the start or end, especially when it gets large.

Setting yourself up with a database is a good step to ensuring your future sanity.  However, you may want to consider the database to use.  Given the simple nature of your dataset, you might want to consider using a no-SQL db like mongodb or even something as simple as sqlite.

If you intend to increase the complexity of your site by say adding captions or locations to your images, then you may want to consider using MySQL/PostgreSQL/etc...

As far as the pagination goes, can you provide some more information on what isn't working?  Are the pages not showing up, is it the wrong number of pages?  Does it always show page 1?  I'll check back and update my post if you can give a little more details.

Comment: Yeah I'll look into setting up a database I suppose. Sqlite is the best right? I mean, it's only me who's going to be uploading, but I intend to put up a lot. Regarding my pagination, when I press 2 on the pagination, it takes me to this page in my root folder, rather than generating a page for the rest of my pictures. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @user657847 I would say there isn't really a "best" database.  sqlite is certainly going to require the least work for you to get up and running as it just uses flat files and the functionality for it is baked into PHP.  For your situation, I think using a relational database like MySQL is probably overkill so try sqlite and see how things go.  What do you mean "this page in my root folder"?  Is it going to test.php but still displaying page 1 images?

Comment: No when I press next, it takes me to what appears to be (domain).com/otherstuff/bibliography.php EXCEPT the url is (domain.com)/test.php?page=2

Comment: @user657847 That sounds like there may be some misconfiguration in your server or htaccess.  If the URL in the address bar is showing /test.php?page=2 then your test.php file is fine.  It's difficult to diagnose further without a lot more information like your vhosts entry for your site and the htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

how would you manage to update an array with 1000 entries by hand?

I would put it in the data in a database. That way you can also filter the data via MySQL before  being processed by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should separate data from the code. In order to add new image you don't want to be editing the code.

Refactor the code by creating a function that reads what images are in your data directory and returns an array with the filenames.

Putting the images into database does not give any further advantage.

Answer (score 0):

First you could easily reduce the size of your array block by using the following (if your images stay in that name scheme):

```
$images = array();

for($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++)
{
    $images[$i] = 'image'.$i.'.jpg';
}
```

About the performance, I believe your approach is a bit faster than using a database but your code could get messy pretty soon. It's way better to separate the the stored data from the actual view logic to be more flexible about designing your code.

Second: about the pagination, what exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: Whoa, that is a nice simple array block! Thanks! And are you sure? I'm thinking of putting up pictures in the long run. At what point (guesstimate) would it be faster to use a database? Regarding my pagination, when I press 2 on the pagination, it takes me to this page in my root folder, rather than generating a page for the rest of my pictures. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: About the pagination problem: it works for me (I tried your script) what do you mean with "it takes me to this page in my root folder" any more info about this? Besides about your performance question: I believe you would barely notice any difference on your use, but think about it once you start doing stuff like filtering images (search etc.) or do more complex operation with your images I would strongly advise using a database.

Comment: Well when I press the next, it takes me to my (domain).com/otherstuff/bibliography.php. That's not what I want. I want it to take me to a generated page which contains the remaining pictures. And any database you recommend? It's only going to be me who's uploading, so I don't need that much of a comprehensive database? Also, any tutorials you recommend regarding database lol. Sorry, I'm a noobie.

Comment: What does the link on the next button look like?

Comment: Well most databases integrate quite nicely with PHP but I guess for a beginner I would recommend mysql, very easy to learn and use. Just google for some php + mysql tutorials there are many (including gallery tutorials)

Comment: The link looks like my bibliography page hah, only difference is the link's url is then (domain.com)/test.php?page=2, rather than (domain).com/otherstuff/bibliography.php. Some guy above recommended sqlite. Sqlite better?

Comment: About SQLite vs MySql check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630/sqlite-vs-mysql sums it up pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use database for large amount data. It is easier to manage. And also you may use [flat file db](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database).